# Loader message while the page loads

Tags: php

I have a php page that takes some time to load because it fetches data from third party APIs. How do I show a loader message while the page loads?

Jquery or Javascript is not an option because I am getting the data from a class call from within the body of the page and not through an AJAX call.

Comment: `https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/` The PACE loader plugin always worked well for me

Comment: Maybe you should use ajax for that content; then you can render the rest of the page and show a nice loader indicator while the visitor is waiting.

Comment: show the api call code

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.load to show loader till page load completes.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```